# Node.js Express Error ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE when using subdomain "www"

Tags: node.js, express

Im trying to use the following code as a reverse proxy. So when I set my pc'ed proxy settings to that, it would redirect Any url to the file.html. But when I type www. in-front of the domain I get error "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" Without the subdomain "www" It works fine. Why is this? And how do I fix it?

```
expressApp.set('port', 6968);
expressApp.use(bodyParser.json());
expressApp.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
expressApp.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('./file.html', {root: __dirname});
});
var server = expressApp.listen(6968);
```